# How to sort list by the text content, which includes numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-lists, materialize

I'm trying to sort this list by the distance (56km,96km,6km) from the lowest to the highest. I know that there are much easier ways to handle and add the li's to the ul, but I need it in this form. The problem is that I have absolutely no Idea and also haven't found something in the Internet.

```
    <ul class="collapsible z-depth-0 assignment " id="assigment_list" style="border: none;">

    </ul>
```

```
const assignmentList = document.querySelector('.assignment');

  const li = `
  <li >
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align"> Nick, 56km from you </div>
  </li>
    <li >
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align">Niclas, 96km from you  </div>
  </li>
  <li >
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align"> Max, 6km from you </div>
  </li>
`;
html += li;
assignmentList.innerHTML = html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your distances as string, not number, you can use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to convert them to number first, then sort. Something like this

```
const distances = ["96km", "6km", "56km"]
// Use parseInt function to get the kilometers as number
const intDistances = distances.map((stringDistance) => {
  // Note that, parseInt stops at the first character that is not number-like
  // So parseInt("6km") will return 6
  const intDistance = parseInt(stringDistance, 10);
    return intDistance;
})
// Sorted
intDistances.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can be helpful for sorting of KMs from lowest to the highest.

```js
var a = ["Nick, 56km from you","Niclas, 96km from you","Max, 6km from you"];
alert("BEGIN WITH: " + a);
var numericPart;
var letterPart;
var max_chars = 4;
var pad_char = 0;
var b = [];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    numericPart = a[i].match(/\d+/);
    numericPart = (new Array(max_chars + 1).join(pad_char) + numericPart).slice(-max_chars); 
    b[i] = numericPart;
}
b.sort(function(a,b){
    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
});
for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = b[i].replace(/0+(?=[1-9])/, '');
}
alert(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way if you have to work with whole strings like `'Nick, 56km from you'`. This answer shows how to sort strings like this, and also shows 2 different ways of adding to the `ul` tag - `innerHTML` and `insertAdjacentHTML`. Please note that showing both ways means the list will show twice in my example.

This is the sorting line:

```
data = data.sort((a,b) => +b.replace(/\D/g,'') - +a.replace(/\D/g,''));
```

It basically says *loop through the data array, and for each item: remove everything but the numbers, and compare*. You'll see `+` before each item. That is to convert them into a number because (for example) while the `replace(/\D/g,'')` removes everything but numbers, the result is still a string, like '56'. Putting the `+` in front changes that into `56` - an actual number. The sort function doesn't change the original data - it just sorts - so to compare things we can convert them like this.

```js
const assignmentList = document.querySelector('.assignment');
let data = ['Nick, 56km from you', 'Niclas, 96km from you', 'Max, 6km from you'];
data = data.sort((a,b) => +b.replace(/\D/g,'') - +a.replace(/\D/g,''));
let ul = document.querySelector('#assigment_list')
// using insertAdjacentHTML
data.forEach(string => ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${string}</li>`));
// using innerHTML
// data.forEach(string => ul.innerHTML += `<li>${string}</li>`);
```

```html
<ul class="collapsible z-depth-0 assignment " id="assigment_list" style="border: none;">

</ul>
```